# imagecolorallocate(): Red component is out of range getting error while getting captcha image

Tags: php, yii1.x

I have a issue with PHP 7.4.5. I have an CaptchaExtendedAction Extension in Yii1 and sometime I get this error:

> imagecolorallocate(): Red component is out of range

at this line

> $foreColor = imagecolorallocate($image, mt_rand($r-50,$r+50),
> mt_rand($g-50,$g+50),mt_rand($b-50,$b+50));

Anybody has an idea how to avoid this?

Comment: RGB bytes must not become less than 0 or greater than 255... if f.e. `$r` is 0 originally, then the rand has a range of -50 to 50, which then can result in negative numbers.

Comment: You can use `min`/`max` to clamp the values down to the valid range.

Comment: @CBroe Not getting exactly Where should I use min / max?

Comment: With the random values you are calculating there. They _can_ go out of the 0 to 255 range, but they mustn't - so clamp 'em down. `min($yourRandomValue, 255)` makes sure the result won't be > 255, `max($yourRandomValue, 0)` makes sure it won't be < 0 - nest both operations into each other, and the result will be "safe" for the intended purpose. `max( min( mt_rand($r-50,$r+50), 255 ), 0 );`

Comment: Using min / max Its working now. Thank you @CBose @
Lars Stegelitz.